# EF Core (C#) - Store calculated column

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.0

I want to store a class with time estimations in my database-table.
This has a few fields:

- BestCase: TimeSpan
- MostLikely: TimeSpan
- WorstCase: TimeSpan

To calculate the result, I've added another property in my class called "Estimated" (Timespan), which is calculated by this formula: (BestCase + 4 * MostLikely + WorstCase) / 6.

To reduce the amount of calculations when getting a huge amount of estimations, I want to store this field also in the database-table. (so store the calculated result)

How can I do this? (with ModelBuilder, or by changing the property?)

I guess that in this case, the result is always calculated when reading the property?

```
public TimeSpan Estimated
{
    get => (BestCase + 4 * MostLikely + WorstCase) / 6;
    set { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better to leave the entity class getters and setters as default.

Try following one of the paths given as example [here](https://www.meziantou.net/2017/07/03/entity-framework-core-generate-tracking-columns).

The simplest, IMHO, is the following solution.

- Leave getters and setters as default
- Override `SaveChanges` and `SaveChangesAsync` in your `DbContext` class to use a method that contains something like the following code:

  ```
  var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries();
  foreach (var entry in entries)
  {
      if (entry.Entity is #insert type of your object#)
      {
          entry.Entity.Estimated = (BestCase + 4 * MostLikely + WorstCase) / 6;
      }
  }
  ```

*Remark:* be aware that with such a solution, the value will not be set if you create an entity and use it in your context before you save to the database.
You can use you solution to provide a value in the case the value is empty on get: in the getter, check if there is a value. If not, make the calculation.